# How do I get the percentage of columns in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm following [this article](https://blog.patricktriest.com/police-data-python/) that's using Pandas.

In there the author states:

> Most traffic stops are of white drivers, which is to be expected since Vermont is around 94% white (making it the 2nd-least diverse state in the nation, behind Maine). Since white drivers make up approximately 94% of the traffic stops, there's no obvious bias here for pulling over non-white drivers vs white drivers. Using the same methodology, however, we can also see that while black drivers make up roughly 2% of all traffic stops, only 1.3% of Vermont's population is black.

But he doesn't show how to figure that using Pandas.

Here's an example of what the data looks like

```
In[165: df_vt['driver_race'].value_counts()
Out[15]:
White       261339
Black         5571
Asian         3446
Hispanic      2562
Other          263
Name: driver_race, dtype: int64
```

I discovered that I could do:

```
df_vt.groupby(('driver_race')).size() / len(df_vt)
```

Which would give me:

```
driver_race
Asian       0.012614
Black       0.020393
Hispanic    0.009378
Other       0.000963
White       0.956651
dtype: float64
```

Which is almost what I want (and it does give me the 2% there), but I'd love to see something like

```
 White     261339     0.956651
 Black       5571     0.020393
 .
 .
 .
 Other        263     0.000963
```

How can I get this using Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple. Calculate `value_counts` and convert it to a dataframe. Then, just calculate the percentage column.

```
vc = df_vt['driver_race'].value_counts().to_frame('counts')
vc['%'] = vc['counts'] / vc['counts'].sum()

vc

          counts         %
White     261339  0.956651
Black       5571  0.020393
Asian       3446  0.012614
Hispanic    2562  0.009378
Other        263  0.000963
```

Comment: Perfect! (I just have to wait 4 more minutes to accept your answer :P)

Comment: @WayneWerner Oh hey, you're the same Wayne from the SOPython chatroom.